# BCP underflow to -Inf

Tags: r

Could anyone translate the below warning into plain English for me ?

> 1: In rcpp_bcpM(y, as.integer(id), as.integer(return.mcmc), as.integer(burnin),  :
>     pbeta(*, log.p=TRUE) -> bpser(a=3630, b=21, x=0.8,...) underflow to -Inf

The input is a column of log returns created as follows :

```
XYZ_xts$LogReturns<-diff(log(XYZ_xts$Adj_Close),lag=10)
```

I have tried the following commands, all of them return the same warnings :

```
XYZ_bcp<-bcp(XYZ_xts$LogReturns)
XYZ_bcp<-bcp(na.omit(XYZ_xts$LogReturns))
XYZ_bcp<-bcp(as.vector(XYZ_xts$LogReturns))
XYZ_bcp<-bcp(as.vector(na.omit(XYZ_xts$LogReturns)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Underflow problems means that there are some operations which can't return the exact number due to limitations of your computer or R. The smallest value your computer/R can handle can be found by `.Machine$double.xmin`, which is equal to `2.225074e-308` on my computer. Underflow warnings occur if you want to calculate a number between 2.225074e-308 and 0.

You are using the `bcp` package for Bayesian Analysis, so you will calculate likelihood functions. Suppose that there are n data points, a likelihood function is then a product of n terms. If n is large and the value of the terms is smaller than one, the likelihood function can underflow to zero.

Comment: Thanks for that. Makes more sense than the obscure error message !  Are you therefore saying that attempting to run bcp against log returns of a couple of years worth of daily data is not the right way to go about things ?

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, but I am sure how to work around this problem since I am not very experienced with Bayesian methods. However take a look at http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2012/07/26/avoiding-underflow-in-bayesian-computations/. I think it will help you